# Performance issues with Dynadock after upgrading to OS X Sierra 10.12.6

Tags: macbook-pro, display, performance, hardware-recommendation

I just took an update today of OS Sierra 10.12.6 on my work laptop (MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)).  Which I had been putting it off until now.

After the upgrade, I noticed that the frame rate on the monitors hanging off my Dynadock are terribly slugish. Full disclosure, I am running 4 monitors AND my laptop screen is open as well.

In terms of delay, it takes about one second after a mouse click to start to see the screen update and another second for it to finish. If I click around a bit, I often get a cascading like delay.

The rate at which the docking bar appeared on monitors that are attached via the dynadock was always very slow, but now everything is just as bad as the docking bar performance on those particular screens.

A quick perusal of Ask Different seems to indicate that no one has ever asked a question about dynadock's with the MacBookPro, so this may be new territory.

Does anyone know who is responsible for the Dynadock drivers? Toshiba doesn't seem to provide a MacOSX driver on their website, yet the Dynadock seems to work perfectly (slugish-ness aside).

I thought it was an Apple thing then, but can find no record of it.
Any ideas of who to reach out to would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is mostly resolved and performance is better.  I went to displaylink.org and downloaded the latest display driver for OSX.  This appears to be the source for OSX compatible Toshiba Displaylink drivers, as Toshiba only seems to publish Windows version on their support site.  After installing the new driver a colleague  mentioned that I should make sure that mission control has screens as "Separate workspaces".

I confirmed that I already had this setting checked, but did a test with it un-checked, and I can confirm that this made update performance worse.

So in general, having the new latest driver did seem to restore performance, however, I am still seeing per application issues.  For instance, I can drag the Safari and Chrome browsers across the Displaylink screens as smooth as butter, but dragging Firefox is choppy and typing into the browser is very difficult to do with any kind of fluidity.